# Yii2 Update many records with difference conditions

Tags: frameworks, yii2, records

I want update many records with yii2 for insert use `batchinsert()` method and for update I don't know!!!

```
update my_tbl set fld1 = 321321 where res = 46513,
               fld1 = 89876 where res = 54646,  
               fld1 = 64564 where res = 54654;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `bacthupdate()` function  in Yii2
Only `batchinsert()` is available

If you want you can iterate and update command or perform a sequence of single update like separate command.

Not also structured solution are actually available in Yii2